# Removing escaped non printable characters from JsonString

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm getting JsonString from client API and there is some non-printable characters(escaped) in that jsonString:

```
"{\"Name\":\"\\u001f\\u001f!#$%&'%\\u0001\"}"
```

I need to remove all this \u001f, \u0001 strings from my string

```
Regex.Replace("{\"Name\":\"\\u001f\\u001f!#$%&'%\\u0001\"}", @"[^\u0020-\u007E]", string.Empty)
```

I tried all regexes and all sanitize functions, nothing works, nothing can catch those strings...

Maybe I'm doing something wrong and you can help me.

Comment: Is that the JSON you're receiving verbatim, or is that the code representation of that string?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar the problem that I can't deserialize it, because it's big Hierarchy of objects... I need then go through all hierarchy with reflection... or something like that

Comment: Could you not wrap the lower level reader from the JSON library of choice and handle strings at that level?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar yes I getting just string like that

Comment: So in the API result you actually have the leading `"`? That's not just as a C# string?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar right

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar API just return me this string, but much bigger, I cut only example part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's match every `\\udddd` and analyze the `dddd` code:

```
string text = "{\"Name\":\"\\u001f\\u001f!#$%&'%\\u0001\"}";

// {"Name":"!#$%&'%"}
var result = Regex.Replace(text,
  @"\\u(?<value>[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})",
   m => char.IsControl((char) int.Parse(m.Groups["value"].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)) 
     ? "" 
     : m.Value);
```

Comment: Hmm... Actually it works, now I need to serealize everything in XML and test it in production :)
One question, as I understand you just remove all non-printable characters ? When you check for IsControl?
Thanks!